# Swift fatal error: Can't form Range with upperBound < lowerBound

Tags: ios, swift, class, for-in-loop

I have a class that I want to add value there with for loop.

This is my class:

```
public class Expandable {
    public var name: String
    public var id:Int

    init(name: String, id:Int) {
        self.name = name
        self.id = id
    }
```

I can add manually like that :

```
let a = [Expandable(name:"aaa", id: 12)]
```

But when I try with for loop, it doesn't work at all.

```
for allin in items{
    sidebarMenuItem?.append(Expandable(name: allin["Code"] as! String, id: allin["Id"] as! Int))
}
```

`Items` data works perfectly, but `sidebarMenuItem` is getting `Optional(MyProjectName.Expandable)` value when I print it.

UPDATE :

I realized that I'm getting the datas well, but I get an error into `expandCell` function :

> fatal error: Can't form Range with upperBound < lowerBound

My expandCell function :

```
private func expandCell(tableView: UITableView, index: Int) {
    // Expand Cell (add ExpansionCells
    if let expansions = sideBarData?[index]?.expandable {
        for i in 1...expansions.count {
            sideBarData?.insert(nil, at: index + i)
            tableView.insertRows(at: [NSIndexPath(row: index + i, section: 0) as IndexPath] , with: .top)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `sidebarMenuItem` is obviously an optional (or is even of type `[Expandable?]`), what do you expect? In many cases it's nonsensical to declare arrays as optional.

Comment: @vadian I did optional, bec I use this class in expandable tableview list. if it's empty, I'm not adding a new expandable list. It's my goal to do.

Comment: **Do not** declare data source arrays as optional and **do not** use optional types in a data source array. Or is the underlying table view optional, too?

Comment: no, tableview is not optional. okay I'll fix that. so what do you suggest for my issue?

Comment: Try `for i in expansions.indices {`

Answer (score 1):

`sidebarMenuItem` is optional because you have declared it optional. Try this.

```
var sidebarMenuItem = [Expandable]()

for allin in items{
    sidebarMenuItem.append(Expandable(name: allin["Code"] as! String, id: allin["Id"] as! Int))
}
```

Comment: it doesn't work either. Now I get fatal error: Can't form Range with upperBound < lowerBound. expand cell doesn't work because I think sidebarMenuItem is empty.

Answer (score 1):

```
// swift 3.0
let k = 5
for i in stride(from: 10, through: k, by: 1) { print("i=\(i)") }
for i in stride(from: 10, to: k, by: 1) { print("i=\(i)") }
```

Comment: Explain your code a bit to make it easier for future readers kindly.

Answer (score 1):

**SWIIFT 4**

To form a range from upperBound to lowerBound use `stride` as by this documentation page: 
[Generic Function stride(from:to:by:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/1641347-stride)

`for i in stride(from: 10, through: 5, by: -1) { print(i) }`

and stride through if you want to include the lowerBound:  [Generic Function stride(from:through:by:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/1641185-stride)

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure how is your expansions structure. But I am guessing it for some cell it might be that your expansion count is 0. That is why its giving this error when your start index is 1 and end index is 0.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
  private func expandCell(tableView: UITableView, index: Int) {
        // Expand Cell (add ExpansionCells
        if let expansions = sideBarData?[index]?.expandable {
            //0 because your first item starts at 0
            for i in 0...expansions.count {
                sideBarData?.insert(nil, at: index + i)
                tableView.insertRows(at: [NSIndexPath(row: index + i, section: 0) as IndexPath] , with: .top)
            }
        }
    }
```